# SQL get distinct first name and last name

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have this query here `select distinct id, FirstName, LastName
                                        from table`

This returns me a list of people, first some of the ids were returning duplicates, but I used `distinct` to fix that, but I still have an issue and that some of the people are duplicates.

Is there also away to put a distinct on the first and last name as well as id? (Some results do not come with an id)

Results (without distinct id):

```
id - 01 - firstname - james - lastname - smith
id - 01 - firstname - james - lastname - smith
id - 02 - firstname - john - lastname - hicks
id - 02 - firstname - john - lastname - hicks
id -    - firstname - tom - lastname - nicks
id -    - firstname - tom - lastname - nicks
```

Expecting:

```
id - 01 - firstname - james - lastname - smith
id - 02 - firstname - john - lastname - hicks
id -    - firstname - tom - lastname - nicks
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. You lost me at "put a distinct on the first and last name as well"... DISTINCT already applies to the entire column list.

Comment: Ok, and what is your query above producing that you don't like? It seems to me that it should produce the results you're expecting. Then again, it is MySQL...

Comment: What's the output you get for this?

Comment: Your problem is clear. If your distinct query is returning then it is not a distinct ID. Meaning you have 
1, Steve, Holt
2, Steve, Holt
Therefore it is giving you distinct results as 1 steve holt <> 2 Steve Holt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have duplicates because you are including `id` in the `select`:

```
select distinct FirstName, LastName
from table;
```

If you need an `id` for a name, then use `group by`:

```
select min(id) as id, FirstName, LastName
from table
group by FirstName, LastName;
```

EDIT:

If you are still getting duplicates with these queries, then you have characters in the names that are throwing things off.  I would start by trimming leading and trailing spaces to see if this fixes the duplicates problem:

```
select min(id) as id, trim(FirstName) as FirstName, trim(LastName) as LastName
from table
group by trim(FirstName), trim(LastName);
```

Comment: Actually, just looking over my list there are still some duplicates.

Comment: they have the same first name, same last name, one has an id, the other does not.

Comment: Then those are not duplicates. You have duplicates in your data. You sir have bad data. This is your problem. Distinct is doing exactly as advertised.

Comment: Is id not the primary key of your table?  If so, how can records not have an id?

Comment: @Zane - duplicate names do not represent bad data, especially if you are dealing with muslims.  There are a lot of Muhammed Ali's out there.

Comment: Wha? Why do some people not have an id? What is the point of that column? If you are identifying "unique" as "one has an id, the other doesn't" then if you have two John Smiths and neither of them have an id, how do you know whether they are the same person or two different people? I'll agree with Zane here - while sometimes your "duplicates" are not really duplicates, this design is going to make it very hard for you to know when that is true and when it is not.

Comment: @DanBracuk I think you are missing my point. Yeah you could have a thousand Ted Stevens's however if some Ted Stevens have an ID and some do not that's bad data and will make it hard to tell what Ted Stevens you are looking for.